# In SR4 how can you make your commlinks, cyberware, drones, etc. harder to hack?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

**Intro**

Came up as a question in my current SR4 game (i didn't like 5th edition much), after a Troll urban samurai with lots of cyberware had his cybereyes hacked, he didn't like the experience much.

I followed the protocol for finding hidden nodes, spoofing commands and etc. (the attacker had some of the same cyberware, so he knew the interface well enough), the experience wizened up the troll to start upping his game and he wants to know what he can do to make his cyberware more difficult to hack.

Some of the other players are newbie runners, some are not, but most of them have either the knowledge (a Technomancer and a Rigger) or have contacts with the knowledge and enough loyalty to share.

**Question**

So, anticipating that the other non-matrix player (a mage), i want to know what sort of things can be done to attain a higher level of security with your devices beyond the "slave all cyberware to a decent commlink running on hidden mode"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protip #1 to protect your wares:

- Slave all to a decent commlink running on hidden mode.

Got that covered? Alright, security of cyberware is actually a topic on *Unwired* and some tips can be found in the book (page 103):

> **Cyberware Defenses**
>
> How can a character protect his cyberware from hacking?
>
> 1.) Turn off or remove any wireless links (see p. 31, Augmentation).
>
> 2.) Use a direct physical connection rather than wireless (externally-accessible implants only)
>
> 3.) Keep the Signal rating low so a hacker would have to be within close range.
>
> 4.) Use a good Firewall program.
>
> 5.) Use a good Encryption program.
>
> 6.) Stay in hidden mode.
>
> 7.) Slave the implant to your secure commlink (see Slaving, *Unwired* p. 55).
>
> 8.) Install Data Bomb, ECCM, or IC programs.

Comment: So far we only have your answer Kras (which is great), i decided to wait till this thursday, if no other answer appears i'll close the question with your answer as the best one.